# Would posting an answer with a Base64-encoded hint be ethically ok?

Tags: discussion, answers, ethics, homework

From time to time, we see those questions with phrases such as "ASAP", "Urgent", etc.

Most of the time it seems to come from students, who messed up in the course. If they followed the instructions of the lecturer, they could mostly solve their issues themselves or at least ask useful questions on Stack Overflow. But they didn't and they kind of hope we as the community would help them out with their problems.

We normally don't do this and explain in the comments why. This also happened recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73667008/a-simple-python-program-need-to-be-solve-asap .

So I ask myself, that it might be kind of funny to help them "somehow". What do I mean with "somehow"? So, for this specific question, I had the following in mind:

I would not present the asker with a complete solution. Instead, only just a hint like the following:

```python
class Student():
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        # This line enables the id process ;)
        self.base64 = "SSBtZXNzZWQgdXAgdGhpcyBzZW1lc3RlciBhbmQgZGlkIG5vdCBmdWxsZmlsIG15IGxlc3NvbnMhIFNvIEkgYXNrZWQgaW4gYSB2ZXJ5IHJ1ZGUgd2F5IG9uIHN0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuIFRoaXMgaXMgdGhlIGxpbms6IGh0dHBzOi8vc3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdy5jb20vcXVlc3Rpb25zLzczNjY3MDA4L2Et c2ltcGxlLXB5dGhvbi1wcm9ncmFtLW5lZWQtdG8tYmUtc29sdmUtYXNhcAo="
```

For you who don't want to decode the `self.base64`:

> I messed up this semester and did not fullfil my lessons! So I asked in a very rude way on stackoverflow. This is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73667008/

At first glance, this sounds a bit evil, but we teach a lot of students programming and mostly need to listen to our gut feeling, when we need to analyze student code.

If I would find one of these Base64-encoded strings in a student's work, it would help me with the gut feeling.

So I think the solution how we handle those issues at the moment is totally fine. I just want to know if the community thinks this could be somehow "funny" or even thinking of something like this should not be considered.

Comment: Ethical? I don't really care. But I fail to see how this is useful, and if it were posted as an answer I'd probably downvote it if I saw it

Comment: Probably not much useful, that's why I brought this late night funny idea as a discussion here, instead of actually follow my late night mind ;)

Comment: If an action makes you feel like you're getting vengeance, retribution, teaching a lesson, or just deserts on a poorly performing student, it is likely an improper action to take.  Best to remember to stay professional. Best if I followed this advice of my own more often than I do.

Comment: It would be better to simply not answer such questions and teach students that they can't simply dump entire homework assignments onto Stack Overflow and expect a solution.  If it never works and just wastes their time, maybe they'll stop eventually.

Comment: Related on meta SE: [Hint-only / Mostly hint answers: desirable or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211842/756727)

Comment: I would instantly downvote an answer like you describe as not being helpful. Of course I would also downvote the question, since I don’t find homework questions to be helpful, but that is besides the point

Comment: Re *"...we teach a lot of students programming and mostly need to listen to our gut feeling, when we need to analyze student code."*: Who are "we"? The Stack Overflow "community"? The organisation you are at?

Comment: Re *"I would not present the asker with a complete solution"*: Why not? Stack Overflow is not a school. It is 99.99999% for ***future readers***, not askers. Any learning is incidental. *Superficially*, it may look like a forum, a help desk, or a virtual [TA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_assistant), but it is not. Stack Overflow's main use case is finding answers through a search engine. Yes, there are [homework tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) which the gamification (and possibly behind-the-scenes payment) keeps going, but that isn't how it should be.

Comment: Mean is not funny.

Comment: Your teaching style lacks empathy.

Comment: @TheMaster I don't lack empathy if someone is willing to engage with the topics of a course. If someone just want to catch easy points I am not open for empathy. On the other hand I had an Idea which came up because the silly question linked. I got the discussion I somehow expected. I don't understand how you could read my actual teaching style from the question.

Comment: It's your attitude. You want to humiliate/punish a student, who is either not willing to do his work or just not interested or just incompetent. I think teaching should be done in a way to inspire, to create willingness and interest. If done properly and successfully, a weak student can be moulded into something beautiful. But you're just trying to mock someone for whatever their reason is, for not doing their work. I just don't think that's good teaching style.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Fun is forbidden, we don't like that here. Whether that's a joke is left as an exercise to the reader. It's true though.

Answers must answer the question, and your suggested proposal for one doesn't.

If you want to post snarky responses, go to Reddit. If you want to retribute, go find another hobby. If you want to feel like you're helping to make the site better: downvote and closevote.

Oh and if you see "ASAP" in a question, edit that out. But don't be too snarky with that edit message either, it won't be as funny nor as constructive as you might think.

Comment: "If you want to feel like you're helping to make the site better: downvote and closevote." And if you're brave enough: comment to explain the relevant policy, especially with the appropriate links to meta or the help section.

Comment: @Karl one can go too far...

Comment: `Fun is forbidden, we don't like that here` Source?

Comment: @TheMaster https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/

Comment: @TheMaster it's officially a [meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268583) of the network :)